# setting environment variable for my VCAP_SERVICES

Tags: linux, macos, cloud-foundry

In `Cloud-Foundry` i have stored my `mongo-secrets` in a `CUPS` and i wanted to replicate the same locally in my mac

These two are the properties

```
vcap.services.mongo-creds.credentials.username=**
vcap.services.mongo-creds.credentials.password=**
```

Before running my app in my local system with `./gradlew bootRun` , i gave these two commands to set these properties for the app to start

```
export vcap.services.mongo-creds.credentials.username=**
export vcap.services.mongo-creds.credentials.password=**
```

I get the below exception in my local-terminal

```
arun$ export vcap.services.mongo-creds.credentials.username=***
-bash: export: `vcap.services.mongo-creds.credentials.username=**': not a valid identifier
arun$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with two rectifications

1. I changed the name from `mongo-creds` to `mongoCreds`. Hyphen wasn't accepted in my `Mac` Terminal
2. I replaced `dot` or `.` with `underscore` or `_` like

`export vcap_services_mongoCreds_credentials_username=***`

The application was able to pick-up these variables

Answer (score 0):

The Bash shell does not allow dots `.` or dashes `-` to be part of variable identifiers.

So, in your `export` expression, when you define a value for the variable `vcap.services.mongo-creds.credentials.username`, Bash tells you the name of this variable is invalid.

One simple solution is to pick another variable name, or use underscores `_` instead.

But for having a relevant `cf push` developer experience on your Mac, I recommend you use [CF Local](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cflocal), instead of building your own ad-hoc setup based on plain Gradle commands. With CF Local, you'll be able to inherit service bindings from a remote Cloud Foundry foundation, including User-Provided Services created with `cf cups`. This should fit your use-case pretty well!